# NSLocalNotification - show notification animation when the app is running in iOS5

Tags: iphone, xcode, uilocalnotification

Is it possible to show `NSLocalNotification` when the app is running and in the foremost position? As the `Apple document` says when the app is in the foremost position the notification will not be shown (it shows in notification center though, just doesn't have the flipping animation on top), then what's the point for method `presentLocalNotificationNow`: ?

Comment: I'll chime in here and state my opinion that the documentation for this stuff is poorly written. I can't answer your question(s), as I don't know myself!

Comment: `-presentLocalNotificationNow` allows you to dispatch a notification immediately when performing a background task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use your own UI to present notifications when your app is active. Use UIApplicationDelegate's [application:didReceiveLocalNotification:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveLocalNotification:) method to find out when a notification is posted.

Answer (score 1):

Notifications are designed to be triggered when the app is no longer active. And by default, they are suppresed if your app is active. So if you tell it to trigger Now, it won't because it won't display any notifications. For something immediate while your app is active, you would use alerts. I don't believe you will be able to override this default behavior.